# JQuery Datepicker Oracle APEX

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex, jquery-ui-datepicker

I hope you are well.

I have an Oracle APEX form (v20) with a DatePicker field.

I only want to display a pop-up when the user clicks on Sunday.

My code :

```
var selector = $("#" + $(this.triggeringElement).parent().find('.apex-item-datepicker').attr('id'));

function showday() {
    day_no = new Date($(this).val()).getDay();
    if(day_no == 0) { //sundays
        alert("its sunday");
    }
}

selector.datepicker("option", {
    onClose : showday
}).next(".ui-datepicker-trigger").addClass("a-Button a-Button--calendar");
```

I have a functional code which is the following but since the APEX datepicker it doesn't work like the demo below: http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/104/

it works in a way that I can't explain, more or less randomly, for example yesterday (before 00h) I had the following result : the pop-up is only displayed on the following Monday.

Thank you in advance for your help, I wish you a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make the pop-up appear using a Dynamic Action. If you set a Dynamic Action Client-side Condition to read the date after the value was changed, you can verify if the date was Sunday.

In my screenshot below I hard coded the timezone to be UTC -4 since I am in the Eastern US timezone.  You may need to adjust that if you so choose. I am also use the format mask YYYY-MM-DD for my date field so if the format mask of your date field is different, the javascript expression in the Client-side Condition may need to change.

I build this demo on apex.oracle.com that you can try out [here](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/adptest/r/ej-testing/alert-on-sunday).

[image: Dynamic Action Example]